# Drupal + LightBox2 component = use body as title (caption) for lightbox

Tags: html, drupal, lightbox, drupal-modules, lightbox2

I am using the LightBox2 component on my website to display the gallery images in a grouped lightbox. I add images to the website by using the `Image` component and adding all the images to the *Photos* book. However, images can still be viewed separately on a page, if I so choose. The url would then look something like this: `www.myurl.com/node/37` with *body* content (that I added in the *Create Image* process) displaying beneath the image.

I was wondering if I can get this *body* content of this new image node page to display as the title for the Lightbox when it opens, if a user clicks on an image in the gallery.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems impossible without hacking the Lightbox2 module.
If you modify Image Gallery's view to include image's body field, you'll be able to hack lightbox2\js\auto_image_handling.js to take body as title.

Answer (score 0):

yes, write a function that prints the html you want to show, register the function with hook_menu, then call it. voila.

e.g.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['lightboxhtml'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_html4lightbox',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    ...
}

function mymodule_html4lightbox($nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  print $node->body;
  exit;
}
```

in the  that calls lightbox, call it with /lightboxhtml/$nid as the href.